# call a page jquery with .submit and nice url

Tags: php, jquery, url-rewriting

I need to call a php page from a search bar using nice urls only and without ?q=blahblah parameters.

```
<form id='searchForm' method="GET" action="/search/">
   <input type="text" name="q" id='idInputWhat' value='' />
   <input id='formSubmit' type="submit" value="go"/>
</form>

$('#formSubmit').on('click', function(e) {
// some validations here
..
// submit
$('#searchForm').submit();
});
```

This would generate an url like: example.com/search/?q=blahblah
My aim is to generate an url like example.com/search/q/blahblah

I was thinking to something like

```
 $('#formSubmit').on('click', function(e) {
     var nice_url = encodeURIComponent($("#idInputWhat").val());
     $('#searchForm').attr('action', 'search/'+nice_url);
     $("#idInputWhat").remove();
    // submit
    $('#searchForm').submit();
});
```

But it does not seem to work and I'm not really sure it's the best approach.

Any ideas?

Comment: You should be using mod_rewrite in your .htaccess file for this.

Comment: Instead of submitting the form, try to just redirect the browser: `location.href = this.action + 'q/' + nice_url;`

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to refresh the page why don't you just do this:

```
$('#formSubmit').on('click', function(e) {
    var nice_url = encodeURIComponent($("#idInputWhat").val());
    window.location = 'search/' + nice_url;
});
```

Comment: I'd prefer not to use redirect if possible!

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that .on() does not works.. it works with .live() even thought it's been deprecated and I'm using jquery 1.8.